# Android Google Analytics - App version reporting

Tags: android, google-analytics

We integrated libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar in our app and it is working fine. By default it includes 'VERSION_CODE' from BuildConfig.java when sending messages to Google Analytics service. I'd like to include 'VERSION_NAME' instead of 'VERSION_CODE'.
1. Is there a way to get a project for libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar?
2. Is there a way to configure libGoogleAnalyticsServices class to send version_name instead of version_code?